# Writing in an open Access DB in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to insert data into an Access database using OLEDB (See example below)

```
Dim strSql = "SELECT * FROM SupplierList"
conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
             ' Set the adapter
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
cmd.CommandText = strSql
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = Me.conn

Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(dataset, "SupplierList")
Dim row = ds.Table(0).NewRow
row.Item(0) = "Name"
row.Item(1) = 12
dataset.Table(0).Rows.Add(row)
da.Update(ds)
```

The code seems to work fine but I noticed that it doesn't do anything if the Access database itself is opened. It has to be closed and not used for the code to take effect. Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to write into an Access DB without requiring having all instances of it closed?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Any Access UI instances just cant have the table designer open for that table and the db cant be open exclusively

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix, so that's just a limitation from Access DB then :)

Comment: Sort of.  Lots of things cant use a file (and that is all an Access DB is) if something else has it open.  Access can, but not if someone opens the file for **exclusive** use or has that table designer open.